# how to Upload jpg file and save it in restplas flask api?

Tags: python, upload, flask-restplus, file-storage

I use `restplus flask api` . I want to upload `jpg` file then rename and save to `files` location. then save its url. I searched and found this code on `https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html#file-upload`, but I dont understand `do_something_with_file` statment in this code. could you help me?

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

upload_parser = api.parser()
upload_parser.add_argument('file', location='files',
                       type=FileStorage, required=True)


@api.route('/upload/')
@api.expect(upload_parser)
class Upload(Resource):
    def post(self):
        uploaded_file = args['file']  # This is FileStorage instance
        url = do_something_with_file(uploaded_file)
        return {'url': url}, 201
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to flask original documentation for uploading files [Uploading files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)

Basically, all you need is [FileStorage.save()](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save) method to save uploaded file.